# Listview with checkbox issue

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a `ListView` that inflate for each row a xml that contain a `CheckBox` and more `TextView`s that are in a `RelativeLayout`.
The problem is that I can't figure out how to pass onClick events from checkbox to back row.
I want to achieve this behavior: The user press the checkbox and the whole list row gets pressed. I saw this behavior if I inflate for each row `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` but I can't figure out how to do that without this android specific layout.

Can anybody give me an idea or direction?

Below is the code:

Listview :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/include_sent_list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

And the xml that is inflated for each row:

```
<RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checked_radio_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_number_text"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        style="@style/config_simple_small_text_view_style"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checked_radio_button"

        />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_name_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        style="@style/config_simple_small_text_view_style"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/account_number_text"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Checkbox consumes focus for the List item.  You need to set this in your layout file:

```
<!-- Must make this non-focusable otherwise it consumes  -->  
<!-- events intended for the list item (i.e. long press) -->
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/item_entry_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    />
```

Comment: I tried this but seems is not working. I guess this is not happening because I inflate this view to list row

Comment: That looks fine.  How about the .java?

Comment: .java code looks like a normal inflating procedure. The screen is inflated correctly but the checkbox get the click events. The android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice can somehow manage to achieve this but I can't figure out how